# Email cannot start with underscore html 5 patterns

Tags: html, validation, email, design-patterns

How to validate an email address through HTML5 pattern so that it cannot be started with underscore.

i have tried with `[?!_]` but it doesnot work

Comment: Why don't you want to allow it to start with an underscore? It's perfectly valid.

Comment: It is a requiement. Although i solved it as
/^(?!_)[a-z0-9]